# CSS3 Center crop image

Tags: image, css, center, crop

I need to center crop images for my responsive webpage 
I want all pictures to been shown in ex. 250x250px like the picture below

How can I do that ?

My result would be like this
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ep02ik9cq39lty9/Screenshot%202014-04-12%2017.07.31.png

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Percentage based width and height for all non-`img` elements
- `250px` for the width and height of the `img` element(s)
- `display:inline-block;` and `text-align:center` for horizontal centering
- `125px` for the top and bottom margin of the `img`

```html
<!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
         <style type="text/css">
         
         /*Set dimensions of image in CSS */
         img { width:250px; height:250px; margin: 125px 0; }
                  
        /* Use inline-block for wrapper and placeholder */
        .placeholder, .wrapper { display: inline-block; }
                               
        /* Inline necessary to use text-align:center */
        .content { display:inline; }
        
        /* Text align for horizontal centering */
        .container { text-align:center; }
         
        .wrapper { width: 100%; }
         
            </style>
        
            <title>Vertical/Horizontal Centering Test</title>
        </head>
         
          <body>
         
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <img src="http://mozilla.com/favicon.ico" alt="test image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="placeholder"></span>
        </div>
          </body>
        </html>
```